# How do you create non-existing folders/subdirectories when copying a file with Java InputStream?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I have used InputStream to succesfully copy a file from one location to another:

```
 public static void copy(File src, File dest) throws IOException { 
       InputStream is = null;
       OutputStream os = null; 

       try { 
           is = new FileInputStream("C:\\test.txt");
           os = new FileOutputStream("C:\\javatest\\test.txt"); 

           byte[] buf = new byte[1024]; 
           int bytesRead; 
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(buf)) > 0) { 
            os.write(buf, 0, bytesRead); 
        } 
       } finally { 
           is.close(); 
           os.close(); 
       } 
   }
```

The problem appears when I add a non-existing folder into the path, for example:

```
os = new FileOutputStream("C:\\javatest\\javanewfolder\\test.txt");
```

This returns a NullPointerException error. How can I create all of the missing directories when executing the copy process through Output Stream?

Comment: By the way, IO streams are autocloseable. You should use them in a try-with statement like the one I used in my answer to this question. Thus you won't need an explicit call to .close(): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if possible I'd recommend you to use the *java.nio.file*  classes (e.g. *Path*), instead of the *File* based approach. You will create Path objects by using a file system. You may use the default filesystem, if no flexibility is needed here:

```
final String folder = ...
final String filename = ...
final FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault(); 
final Path myFile fs.getPath(folder, filename);
```

Then your problem is easily solved by a very convenient API:

```
final Path destinationFolder = dest.getParent();
Files.createDirectories(myPath.getParent());
try (final OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(myFile)) {
  ...
}
```

The Files.createDirectories() method will not fail if the directory already exists, but it may fail due to other reasons. For example if a file "foo/bar" exists, Files.createDirectories("foo/bar/folder") will most likely *not* succeed. ;)

Please read the javadoc carefully!

To check, if a path points to an existing directory, just user:

```
Files.isDirectory(somePath);
```

If needed, you can convert between *File* and *Path*. You will lose file system information, though:

```
final Path path1 = file1.toPath();
final File file2 = path2.toFile();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Files.createDirectories](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-):

```
Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("C:\\javatest\\javanewfolder"));
```

Also, you could use `Files.copy` to copy file )